# Why do I speak in a lower (deeper) voice in foreign languages compared to my mother tongue

Tags: pitch-accent

I'm a native German speaker. I myself and friends have noticed, that when I speak in English, my voice becomes lower (deeper) and if I speak in Finnish, even lower than in English. If I concentrate I can change it back to a higher pitch, but subconciously I fall back to lower pitch levels. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Everyone speaks about three octaves lower in Finnish than in other languages, so that one makes sense.

Comment: A former colleague used to speak in a lower pitch in English than in her native German, but in a higher pitch in French.  Since she would switch languages mid-sentence, this was very helpful to listeners to signal which she was using, and perhaps to her too.

Comment: Just for fun we checked, and my French is also in a higher pitch.

Comment: I suspect more velarization and dark vowels?

Comment: Three octaves lower? Hmm. //How exactly did you check? I'd like to check my four languages.

Comment: I would guess that it's a side effect of speaking more artificially, though that is contradicted by Henry's anecdote.